# Fetching data attributes from instagram hashtag

Tags: php, json, instagram

I want to fetch data(the images in each post) stored in https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/selfie/?__a=1, but all I get when I decode and var_dump this is NULL.

```
$obj = json_decode("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/selfie/?__a=1", true);
var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: How do I fetch the "profile_pic_url"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to `json_decode` the STRING

`https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/selfie/?__a=1`

What you need to do is to fetch the URL first.  I suggest using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), which takes a URL and returns the contents at the end of that URL.

Try this:

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/selfie/?__a=1");
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: That's a different question about traversing a JSON structure.  I'd accept the best answer here, then ask another question for that.

Answer (score 2):

Before decoding json you have to first fetch api response.

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/selfie/?__a=1"), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument to the function json_decode(), $html must be plaintext/string.
This should work.

```
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/selfie/?__a=1";
$html = file_get_contents($url); 
$obj = json_decode($html,true);
var_dump($obj);
```

See this in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/UnselfishBlindProcedurallanguage)